# PHP How correctly check row on symbols array?

Tags: php, arrays, find

Good day.

```
$Symbols = array('1','2','3','4','45','100','0');
$row = '120321'; //for example
```

how check `$row` on symbol in array?

P.S.: IE. if `$row` have one or some symbols from `$Symbols` than print yes.

Comment: use in_array() in PHP http://in1.php.net/in_array

Comment: you want to match $row value or each char exist in row

Comment: @RakeshSharma i would like get print count values symblos from `$Symbols` in `$row`

Comment: @learner checkout my answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per you comment I think you want counter of all element in array present in the `$row`:

```
<?php
    $counter = 0;
    $Symbols = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '45', '100', '0');
    $row = '120321'; //for example

    foreach ($Symbols as $sym) {
        if (strpos($row, $sym) !== false) {
            $counter++;
        }
    }
    echo $counter; // It will give you the counter of all element in array present in the $row
  ?>
```

[**See live DEMO**](http://3v4l.org/anDON)

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple, actually:

```
if (array_intersect($Symbols, str_split($row))) {
    echo 'Yes';
}
```

Here, we use [`str_split()`](http://php.net/str_split) split the `$row` array into an array of characters and then use [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/array_intersect) to check if it has any elements in common with `$Symbols` array. Note that this would however fail for numbers like 100 though.

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/135421)

Comment: we need check `$row` on exists symbols from array `$Symbols` if `$row` have symbol from `$Symbols` than print `yes`.

Comment: @learner: Could you please write the sentence with proper punctuation? It's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I mean the following: i have array symbols(`$Symbols`) and i have row (`$row`). I want to check for the existence of one or more characters from the array `$Symbols` in row `$row`.

Comment: @learner: That's exactly what this code does. Did you try it? Check the demo.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work for numbers > 9:

```
foreach($Symbols as $symbol){
    if(strpos($row,$symbol) !== false){
        echo "Yes";
        break;
    }
}
```

[Example](http://3v4l.org/WhV9H)

Comment: What if the string was `200100`? According to this logic, all these numbers would return `Yes`: 2, 200, 2001, 0, 10, 100.

Comment: @AmalMurali Unless I'm misunderstanding that's what the asker wants `if $row have one or some symbols from $Symbols than print yes`. `200100` matches one or more of the symbols so would print `Yes`.